# aura:if inside aura:set rendering empty value even if isTrue turns out to be false

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, aura-if, aura-set

I have markup as:

> Parent Component:

```
<!--SOME MARKUP-->
    <c:modal title="Modal Title">
       <aura:set attribute="right">
         <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.hideModal}"/>
          <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDoneAllowed}">---THIS IS FALSE
                 <lightning:button variant="neutral" aura:id="writeInTopicBtn" label="Done"/>
           </aura:if>
        </aura:set>
    </c:modal>
<!--SOME MARKUP-->
```

> c:modal:

```
<!--SOME MARKUP-->
    <div class="slds-float--right">
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.right}" var="action">
            TEST TEXT
              <span class="slds-p-horizontal--x-small">{!action}</span>
          </aura:iteration>
    </div>
<!--SOME MARKUP-->
```

This test text gets rendered 2 times even if my isTrue was false and it should have shown only once. How can this be avoided, is there any workaround. And is this a known bug in SF?

Comment: try replacing `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDoneAllowed}">` with `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDoneAllowed == 'true'}">`

Comment: @ItaiShmida: Giving same results.

Comment: What type is `isDoneAllowed` attribute? are you sure that it's value is false? try replacing in the if statement into: `<aura:if isTrue="{!true}">` - does that work for you?

Comment: @ItaiShmida : Yes, it is false, I printed it in markup before aura:if. Let me reverify and try  using {!true}